# Why a lint warning about fullBackupContent warning when allowBackup is false?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-backup-service, android-lint

For an app with `android:allowBackup="false"`, Android lint reports:

> Should explicitly set 'android:fullBackupContent' to avoid backing up the GCM device specific regId.

Is this just a bug in the lint rule, or do I really need to be concerned about the regId getting backed up and restored onto another device?

Comment: [Background on fullBackupContent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30804168/145173)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181805) that was fixed in AS 1.4. Now you only get this lint warning when `allowBackup="true"` or the attribute is missing (which defaults to true)

Comment: Still broken for me in AS 1.5. More frustratingly, it is broken from the command line gradle lint task.

Comment: Can you please tell me the version of the gradle plugin you're using? I cant' repro this with 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'

Comment: I was using version 1.3.1 of the gradle plugin. With that version I couldn't even suppress the error. Updating to 1.5.0 fixed it, although it did introduce a couple of other problems unrelated to this question.

Comment: @jeff good to know that it's resolved. Are the other problems issues that you see in lint rules?

Comment: One of the other problems is a lint rule: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194705 In my case, it's a service description that's triggering the lint warning. The other problem is with JaCoCo: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192875 With the latter problem, if I don't apply the workaround to the top-level build.gradle file, I cannot execute any gradle tasks. I was previously trying to avoid updating to 1.5.0 due to this. Hard to believe the plugin was released with this kind of regression.

Comment: Are you getting the lint issue with a resource or a description? (description was fixed in 1.5.1

Comment: It's for a service that has a translated description. e.g., `<service android:name=".foo.MyService" android:description="@string/my_service_description" />`